# Размытие главного окна после показа другого виджета

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, paintevent, qgraphicsblureffect

У меня есть в код, в котором после нажатия на кнопку **`"Выбрать цвет"`** показывается виджет, который находиться в `gridlayout`.

Надо сделать так, чтобы при показа виджета, после нажатия на кнопку `"Выбрать цвет"` все главное окно должно размыться (`gaussian blur`), а после закрытия виджета выбора цвета все должно возвращаться.

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(695, 414)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(695, 414))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(695, 414))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 701, 421))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(121, 121, 121);")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.fontComboBox = QtWidgets.QFontComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.fontComboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 192, 21))
        self.fontComboBox.setEditable(False)
        self.fontComboBox.setObjectName("fontComboBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 380, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 651, 291))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 30, 161, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.fontComboBox.setCurrentText(_translate("MainWindow", "MS Shell Dlg 2"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать цвет"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Найти..."))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)


        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def onClicked(self):
        self.exampleApp2 = ExampleApp2()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.exampleApp2, 0, 0, 1, 1)


class Ui_MainWindow_color(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(277, 323)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(277, 323))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(277, 323))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 701, 421))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: green")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 231, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 290, 81, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Green"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "White"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Black"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Purple"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "Red"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "Yellow"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "Orange"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Продолжить"))

class ExampleApp2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow_color):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

    def clicked(self):
        self.close()


if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Класс QGraphicsBlurEffect обеспечивает эффект размытия.**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow_color(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(277, 323)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(277, 323))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(277, 323))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 701, 421))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: green")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 231, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 290, 81, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Green"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "White"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Black"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Purple"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "Red"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "Yellow"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "Orange"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Продолжить"))


class ExampleApp2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow_color):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
#    def clicked(self):
#        self.close()


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(695, 414)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(695, 414))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(695, 414))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 701, 421))
#        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(121, 121, 121);")    # --- !!!
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.fontComboBox = QtWidgets.QFontComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.fontComboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 192, 21))
        self.fontComboBox.setEditable(False)
        self.fontComboBox.setObjectName("fontComboBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 380, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 651, 291))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 30, 161, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.fontComboBox.setCurrentText(_translate("MainWindow", "MS Shell Dlg 2"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать цвет"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Найти..."))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.plainTextEdit.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial', 15))
        self.plainTextEdit.setPlainText('Hello World !')
        self.effectFlag = False

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def onClicked(self):
        self.exampleApp2 = ExampleApp2()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.exampleApp2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.exampleApp2.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clickedApp2)      

        self.effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect()  
        self.effect.setBlurRadius(3)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)  
        self.plainTextEdit.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgba(121, 252, 50, 200);')
        self.effect2 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
        self.effect2.setBlurRadius(2)        
        self.pushButton.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect2)
        self.effect3 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
        self.effect3.setBlurRadius(2)        
        self.fontComboBox.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect3)
        self.effect4 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
        self.effect4.setBlurRadius(2)        
        self.lineEdit.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect4)

        self.fontComboBox.setEnabled(False)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.plainTextEdit.setEnabled(False)
        self.lineEdit.setEnabled(False)

        self.effectFlag = True
        self.update() 


    def clickedApp2(self):                                                 # +++
        self.effect.setBlurRadius(0)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)
        self.plainTextEdit.setStyleSheet('background-color: #fff;')
        self.effect2.setBlurRadius(0)        
        self.pushButton.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect2)
        self.effect3.setBlurRadius(0)
        self.fontComboBox.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect3)
        self.effect4.setBlurRadius(0)        
        self.lineEdit.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect4)        

        self.effectFlag = False
        self.update()        

        self.exampleApp2.close()        
        self.fontComboBox.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.plainTextEdit.setEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit.setEnabled(True)

    def paintEvent(self, event):                                             # +++ 
        if self.effectFlag:
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)      
            brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
            brush.setColor(QtGui.QColor(121, 252, 50, 200)) 
            painter.setBrush(brush)
            painter.drawRect(self.rect())          
        else:
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)                
            brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
            brush.setColor(QtGui.QColor(121, 121, 121, 220)) 
            painter.setBrush(brush)
            painter.drawRect(self.rect())                  


if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    app.setStyle('Fusion')       #  можете попробовать без этой строки 

    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]